# Use of protocol_id in SMPP

Tags: java, sms, smpp

I am working on an SMPP based application and trying to send SubmitSM using SMPP protocol.Currently a bit counfused about some of the PDU params that are available in SubmitSM. Anybody have some idea or any reference how the **protocolId** is used in SMPP or in SMSC. Done some research but couldn't really found anything that explain it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **1.2.13 protocol_id TP-PID (Protocol identifier)** here : https://www.sysop.fr/index-smpp/